# How to secure Auth0 credentials in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I've been following the auth0 react tutorial for single page applications. but for the life of me I can't figure out how to protect the auth0 API key credentials. In the tutorial you create an Auth0Provider component that its passed the Auth0's domain, clientid and audience keys.

```
<Auth0Provider
  domain={process.env.domain}
  client_id={process.env.clientid}
  redirect_uri={window.location.origin}
  audience={process.env.audience}
  onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}>
  <App />
</Auth0Provider>
```

Now, this component lives in the client side and when you bundle the application code, the process.env variables are converted to the real values and there's nothing stopping the user to see that data if he simply inspects the application code.

What am I missing?. I know you're not supposed to store sensitive information in the client's code, but (correct me if I'm wrong) the auth0 documentation don't offer another alternative.

The server should be in charge of handling this credentials and making the requests on behalf of the Auth0Provider component, so ideally if the Auth0Provider component could do an ajax request to the server that would solve the problem.

Comment: These information is safe to share in the frontend client. Client secret is important one which is not required for SPA.